# Ole atomation in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, com, ole

I write vbs that create ole atomation object

```
On Error Resume Next
dim objShell
dim objFolder      
if not objFolder is nothing then
objFolder.CopyHere "ftp://anonymous:123@ftp.microsoft.com/bussys"
WScript.Sleep 100
end if 
set objShell = nothing
set objFolder = nothing
```

How to do that on C# (or do that without ole automation just use com) ? Or do that on c++ without MFC.

Comment: What have you tried already? Where are you stuck? Do you want the exact same code or something that does what you want? If so, what do you want?

Comment: Yes i want same code. I want download directory from ftp protocol.

Comment: Ah, I see now you already found an answer on how to do it in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514990/translate-from-c-to-c-closed It indeed does the exact same as this VBS code. This is not how I would do it though. Why not focus on the result (ftp directory download) instead of insisting doing it one way. And why ask for C# of you really want it in c++?

Comment: in c++ other peoples said me that i need some 3d party Libraries because there is not standart functions in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. I think if i write this program on c# i can to do that on c++ too because that both languages using .NET. Now i now that i need write the recursive function or search 3d party library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/desktopapplications/article.php/c13163) you will find an article on how to do FTP from C#. Basically it uses the [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class. I am sure you now have enough information to write the code yourself.

In order to download whole directories you would need to look for the files in the folder (ListFolder method) and then download all the files (DownloadFile for each file).

Comment: i want to download folders not files